# How to fix ngons overlapping wire edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bmesh

I am trying to make a retopo of my human head. But it seems that I already have several ngons because I couldn't create an edge loop.

So I checked it with mesh lint and it showed me the ngons

[image]

But the ngons are really quads as far as I can see.

Any idea why this is happening?

[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27355)

Comment: Please upload blend-file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a large ngon face over the other faces. The same thing goes for the bottom of the nose and the chin. To fix this delete the large polygon and bridge the edges.

1. Select the large ngon faces:

   [image]
2. Delete the faces only

   [image]
3. Use bridge to add new polygons. Or you can fill them one by one using the fill tool: <kbd>F</kbd>

   [image]   [image]
4. Do the same for the bottom of the nose and the chin.

---

[image]

Comment: I already tried that but that wasn't the problem. I've also uploaded the blend file itself.

Comment: Oh .. I should have looked at the faces. Thank you very much.

Comment: Alternatively, just go to _Mesh > Cleanup > Delete Loose_. Then delete the ngon and fill back the faces.

Comment: @iKlsR I tried this and it deletes the edges. The ngon is still there

Comment: I think this answer involves too much manual editing, since we have tools to fill in empty regions (added own answer), also, You could use **Select Path** before the bridge operation. one more thing - you can select all 3 edge loops and run bridge once.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways I would suggest to fix up a model with edges like this.

**Using Fill holes:**

*This tool was written for almost this exact case, it has the advantage it will fill in UV's. vertex-colors and materials from surrounding geometry.*

[See the docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Cleanup)

- Delete the ngons (Only Faces), <kbd>x, n</kbd>
- Select all, <kbd>a</kbd>
- Mesh -> Cleanup -> Fill Holes

**Using Face Create:**

*The default face creation will fill a wire-net of faces too, but in this case it goes too far and needs one face removed.*

- Delete the ngons (Only Faces), <kbd>x, n</kbd>
- Select all,<kbd>a</kbd>
- Mesh -> Faces -> Make Face/Edge, <kbd>f</kbd>
- delete the large ngon created at the back.

Comment: This answer is actually better. I never knew blender had these modeling tools, they must be new

Comment: @Vader, Yes they are fairly new - added last release http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.69/Modeling#Mesh_Editing

Comment: I s there a way to access the clean using keyboard shortcuts? I would expect them to be in the specials menu

Comment: No, they are intended to be tools you run to fix bad imported models to save manual work, but not used for general workflow. Note that 2.70 adds more cleanup tools http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/Modeling#Mesh_Cleanup

Comment: They seem to be pretty useful to me for general modeling, even if that's not what they were intended as.